# Linux kernel programming

Tags: linux-kernel

i want to catch pipe() syscall, so i've changed source code in pipe.c

```
static pipe_hook_t pipe_hook;
pipe_hook_t set_pipe_hook(pipe_hook_t hook)
{
    pipe_hook_t old_hook = pipe_hook;
    pipe_hook = hook;
    printk(KERN_INFO, "pipe hook: %p", hook);
    return old_hook;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(set_pipe_hook);
```

then i tried to define pipe_hook_t in file syscalls.h (included in pipe.c)

```
typedef void (*pipe_hook_t)(int *filedes);
pipe_hook_t set_pipe_hook(pipe_hook_t hook);
```

and i have error:

```
fs/pipe.c:1130: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘pipe_hook’
fs/pipe.c:1131: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘set_pipe_hook’
fs/pipe.c:1138: error: ‘set_pipe_hook’ undeclared here (not in a function)
fs/pipe.c:1138: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘set_pipe_hook’
fs/pipe.c: In function ‘sys_pipe2’:
fs/pipe.c:1153: error: ‘pipe_hook’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fs/pipe.c:1153: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
fs/pipe.c:1153: error: for each function it appears in.)
fs/pipe.c:1154: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pipe_hook’
```

i've tried to create my own .h file and define pipe_hook_t there but the error was the same

Comment: If you declare the typedef right before the `set_pipe_hook()` implementation, do you still get the error?  It looks like you are missing the `typedef` maybe due to conditional compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. I've just confused directory where header files are.